# GetElementsByTagName for a without href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vb.net

I am reading the class of all the elements `<a>` in a webpage's HTML document from a VB.net WinForm:

```
  Dim htmlLinks As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
  For Each link As HtmlElement In htmlLinks
    Console.WriteLine(link.GetAttribute("classname").ToString)
  Next
```

Here's a small example from the HTML document :

```
<a href=​"/​test.php" class=​"nav">Item1</a> 
<a class=​"link-download" href=​"http:​/​/​test.net/​media/​26.mp4">​​MP4 File</a>​
```

The VB code I wrote above is only reading `Class` attribute the `a` where `href` element comes first,

```
<a href=​"/​test.php" class=​"nav">Item1</a>
```

and missing the second one where `class` attribute comes before `href`

```
 <a class=​"link-download" href=​"http:​/​/​test.net/​media/​26.mp4">​​MP4 File</a>​
```

Means my VB code is only returning the class name `nav`

Does this make sense?

I need to read all the `<a>` elements above

how can I do that?

Comment: What is the purpose of your code? Are you scraping web data? If so I would recommend the CSQuery library as it uses jQuery style selectors to fetch data from HTML.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I am using the code to extract the "href" element for certain classes and save the link inside it.

Comment: can you debug your code  and tell us what is the count for `htmlLinks`

Comment: So you *are* just scraping web data :) In that case please *do* consider using CSQuery to make the code both shorter and simpler. CSQuery is not suited to modifying the DOM, but is perfect for read-only tasks.

Comment: I can't get my head around the `GetAttribute("classname")`.

Comment: Count of `htmlLinks`=1 means that the problem is with `GetElementsByTagName("a")`, and not the `GetAttribute("classname")`. Now the question is why it picked only one `A` element!

Answer (score 2):

I made a test html page with the html text you posted. The VB code works ok for me. I get two elements in the collection. However, there are some junk characters in them. I just enabled hidden characters to verify and indeed I see junk characters. Removing those characters fixes everything.

[image: junk characters in html text]

Comment: Nice find. It's a zero-width space by the way, U+200B. Although I'm not sure why you get two elements and the OP's complaint is they get only one.

Comment: @MrLister, I really don't know, but my wildest guess would be that it has something to do with the parent of these elements. In my file, I just typed it, so there would be no junk characters etc. But in his case, there might be something bad with the parent elements.